# Limit the word count in the post title

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to limit the word count of the post title?

Ive search over the internet but nothing found.

All I know is, only the content of the post can be limit or excerpted.

Comment: simple solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/291096/133699

Answer (score 4):

simply use this where ever you want to display your title with limited words

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5 ); ?>
```

replace number 5 in above code with whatever number of words you need to display.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The following will limit the number of *characters* a user can enter in the *admin area*, i.e., when writing a post.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'so_13816272_limit_input_title' );

function so_13816272_limit_input_title(  )
{
    global $current_screen;
    // Not our post type, exit earlier
    if( 'post' != $current_screen->post_type )
        return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
        {
            $('#title').keyup( function() 
            {
                var $this = $(this);
                if($this.val().length > 50)
                    $this.val($this.val().substr(0, 50));           
            });           
        });     
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

If you want to do a *word* count, refer to [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-count-words-textarea-input/) and adapt the functions into the above code.